# My footer in CSS does not pay attention to my right and left content, only to the middle content

Tags: html, css, layout

Ok this is my problem:
The left float and right float are somehow not put into my container and the footer only pays attention to the middle content part. What am I doing wrong?
I could show it with a picture but I cannot add one because I don't have 10 rep.
It must be a simple fix, I have read about clear:both etc but that all does not work unfortunately.

```
#container
{
    position: relative;
    width: 58.5%;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #336600;
    text-align: left;

    }
#header
{
    height: 160px;
    background-image:url(images/bannerboven.jpg);
}
#sideleft
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 160px;
    left: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 22%;
    background: #CCFFFF;
    padding: 15px 10px 15px 20px;
}

#sideright
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 160px;
    right: 0;
    float:right;
    width: 23%;
    background: #CCFFFF;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    padding: 15px 10px 15px 20px;
}
#mainContent
{
    margin: 0 26% 0 26%;
    padding: 0 10px;
    background:  #0F0;
    }
#footer
{
    padding: 0 10px 0 20px;
    background: #DDDDDD;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    }
```

Comment: Please create a demo using http://jsfiddle.net/ or some other similar service.

Comment: You're trying to absolutely position some elements and float them at the same time. That is always going to cause problems. It's one or the other. Post up your HTML code too please.

Comment: Post up your HTML and css  jsfiddle.net  here  save it and post URL please

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve without knowing your html structure, but the problem stems from the fact that you have absolute positioning on your left and right containers as well as a floted positioning.

The default positioning for a html element is static, so you either float everything or absolute position everything. Here's something to help you understand positioning better, it's very easy and you'll be on your way in 5 minutes: http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Also, you should post a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) link with the html included so we'll understand better what you are trying to achieve if you need further help. My guess is that Rohit Azad's solution is correct, you just have trouble understanding positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i check to your code i think you want to this

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">Header</div>

  <div id="mainContent">
    <div id="sideleft">Left</div>
    <div id="sideright">Right</div>
  </div>

  <div id="footer">Footer</div>

</div>
```

**Css**

```
#container
{

    width: 58.5%;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #336600;

    }
#header
{
    height: 160px;
  background:red;
    background-image:url(images/bannerboven.jpg);
}
#sideleft
{
float:left;    width: 22%;
    background: #CCFFFF;
    padding: 15px 10px 15px 20px;
}

#sideright
{
float:right;
  width: 23%;
    background: #CCFFFF;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    padding: 15px 10px 15px 20px;
}
#mainContent
{
    padding: 20px 10px;
    background: green;
overflow:hidden;
    }
#footer
{
    padding: 0 10px 0 20px;
    background: #DDDDDD;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    }
```

***[Live demo](http://tinkerbin.com/5H2yspUE)***

Comment: Doens't make any difference =/

Comment: I just want the banner beneath my 3 items in the middle and not just beneath the mainContent.
So this is what it shows wrong:
http://img210.imageshack.us/img210/4075/thesite.jpg

As you can see the banner is not under the right column as it should be.

Comment: Never mind, got it, I just had to put the middle 3 colums in a different container :) Rohit Azad's solution was almost wat I needed :p
Thanks all!